# Does R have issues with numerical stability?

Tags: r, numerical

I am trying my hand at writing a simulation of a ranking model in R. I seem to have run into something that may have to do with "numerical stability". I was wondering if someone could suggest some workaround or way to handle it.

```
ranking_algo_fn<- function(old_rank, website_choice,kappa)
 {  
   v<- (kappa/ (1+ kappa))
   new_rank<- (v*old_rank)+((1-v)*website_choice)
   return(new_rank)
 }
```

I've traced the problem to this function. Basically this is an updating function, which iterates over the agents performing some action - `website choice`

Ranks are a vector of probabilities (summing to 1 - as it should). Starting with a uniform distribution - so if there were 20 websites, this would be 0.05 for each. ie [0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,....]

The problem is that intuitively, each subsequent `new_rank` should sum to 1, but it doesn't. Plotted it basically takes a life of it's own, (different behavior based on different parameters, but never what it should). See the attached image for one such instance.

[image: Random_jitters]

The plot of the sum of `website_choice` and all other things ingredients coming before, is always a straight line. Any workaround?

I've been told that it's better to use other softwares like MATLAB or Mathematica for this kind of stuff. Is that true?

Comment: Numerical instability is an issue of computers in general (more precisely, of fixed-precision storage of floating point numbers) and algorithms specifically. It’s not something that R can/should do anything about (except as it provides libraries that implement algorithms). Since the problem is in your computation, you’ll need to deal with numerical stability yourself. Neither Matlab nor Mathematica will handle this differently.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me a good deal from rewriting the whole thing in MATLAB!